# Invalid argument, not a string or column when using a UDF

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a data quality class to perform checks on a df. I use methods defined in this class to run these checks (they always return tuples of 3). These methods are called by a udf that I want to call from another df:

```
@F.udf(StructType())
def dq_check_wrapper(df, col, _test):
  
  if _test == 'is_null':
    return Valid_df(df).is_not_null(col).execute()

  elif _test == 'unique':
    return Valid_df(df).is_unique(col).execute()
```

Say I want to asses the DQ on this df:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
     (None, 128.0, 1),(110, 127.0, 2),(111, 127.0, 3),(111, 127.0, 4)
    ,(111, 126.0, 5),(111, 127.0, 6),(109, 126.0, 7),(111, 126.0, 1001)
    ,(114, 126.0, 1003),(115, 83.0, 1064),(116, 127.0, 1066)
  ], ['HR', 'maxABP', 'Second']
)
```

To make it dynamic, I want to use a metadata df:

```
metadata = sqlContext.sql("select 'HR' as col, 'is_null' as dq_check")

+---+--------+
|col|dq_check|
+---+--------+
| HR| is_null|
+---+--------+
```

But then, when I try:

```
metadata\
  .withColumn("valid_dq", dq_check_wrapper(df, metadata.col, metadata.dq_check))\
  .show()
```

I get a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: DataFrame[HR: bigint, maxABP: double, Second: bigint] of type <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Because if I don't inform that df is of type DataFrame, it infers as String:

```
def dq_check_wrapper(df: DataFrame, col, _test):
```